# Выборка данных в цикле do while

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется два select из бд.

```
/*Извлекаем категории номеров*/    
$resultNmb = mysql_query("SELECT id,category,colvo_chelovek FROM hotel_number",$db);    
$myrowNmb = mysql_fetch_array($resultNmb);        

/*Извлекаем ценовые сезоны*/    
$resultPrice = mysql_query("SELECT id_hotel_number,begin_season,end_season,price,quotaNumber FROM price_season WHERE id_hotel_number = '".$myrowNmb['id']."'",$db);    
$myrowPrice = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrice);
```

Один выбирает категории номеров, другой в зависимости от первого выбирает ценовые сезоны этих категорий номеров. Далее в HTML таблице эти данные выводятся циклом do while. Т. е. выводится категория номера и в ней должно быть несколько ценовых сезонов. Я смог это реализовать только делая выборку ценовых сезонов прям в цикле do while, который отображает все категории номеров. Но ведь не рекомендуется делать подобные выборки в циклах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как же правильно сделать выборку и отобразить эти данные?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать join.

Comment: Примерно можешь показать как его на этом примере применить?

Comment: тут даже join не понадобилсяselect * from hotel_number, price_season WHERE proce_season.id_hotel_number=hotel_number.id

Answer (score 1):

Легко

```
mysql_query("SELECT h.id, h.category, h.colvo_chelovek,
  p.id_hotel_number, p.begin_season, p.end_season, p.price,
  p.quotaNumber FROM hotel_number h, price_season p
  WHERE p.id_hotel_number = h.id",$db)
```

Comment: А как же вывести данные на экран так, чтобы были показаны все извлечённые `hotel_number` и под каждым конкретным `hotel_number`, выводилось несколько соответствующих ему `price_season`?Т.е. у меня получился цикл где я выводил `hotel_number` и в этом цикле ещё один цикл(выборка `price_season`, вывод на экран). Буду очень благодарен, если поможете разобраться в щекотливой ситуации!